# What is the decimal part in timestamp?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, python-datetime

I run the following code in python,

```
import time
print(time.time())
```

and the output was:

`1557990717.6383634`

Can someone explain the two parts to the left and right of the decimal point. Why's there a decimal point?

Comment: `0.5` means half second

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As stated in the [official documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html#time.time), `time.time()` returns a floating point number which represents the amount of seconds since the epoch. The number on the left side of the point represents seconds, the number on the right side represents the milliseconds between the seconds.

If you would only want the amount of seconds since epoch you can use:

```
round(time.time())
```

If you would want only the millisecond part, you could use:

```
time.time() % 1
```

Answer (score 2):

time.time() → float

Return the time in seconds since the epoch as a floating point number. The specific date of the epoch and the handling of leap seconds is platform dependent. On Windows and most Unix systems, the epoch is January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 (UTC) and leap seconds are not counted towards the time in seconds since the epoch. This is commonly referred to as Unix time. To find out what the epoch is on a given platform, look at gmtime(0).

[docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html)

Answer (score 0):

Read documentation [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html)

The left hand side is the number of seconds since January 1, 1970, 00:00:00. The number of seconds can be a non integer, i.e milliseconds, etc.